# Are there any algorithms for extracting functions from expressions?

Tags: compilers

Suppose you have an expression like this:

```
sqrt(x) * 6 + sqrt(x + 1) * 6 + sqrt(x + 2) * 6
```

Are there any well-known or published algorithms that can find the repeated partial expressions and extract a function like this?

```
let f(x) = sqrt(x) * 6
 in f(x) + f(x + 1) + f(x + 2)
```

I imagine there are some clever schemes in either the automatic vectorization literature or in automatically finding duplicate code. This is also somewhat similar to common subexpression elimination.

Comment: I think it's a part of [automatic] code refactoring techniques. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_code